# maximum likelihood function for suvey

Tags: statistics

> Suppose we have some participants in a survey, each of them flips a fair coin and keeps the result ("heads" or "tails") to themselves.
>
> Then the participants are asked two benign questions like ("Do you like chocolate ?") and supposed to answer the first question with "yes" or "no" if their coin landed on "heads" and the second question with "yes" or "no" if the coin landed on tails.
>
> The proportion $p_B$ of people answering the second question with "yes" is known, find an estimator of the unkown probability $p_A$ (people answering the first question with yes)

Since we have $n$ independt coin-flips, I tend to use the binomial distribution.

$$p_x(v)=\binom{n}{x}v^x \cdot (1-v)^x$$.

Since the coin is "fair", we have $v=0.5$.
I am a little confused how I can solve the problem.

Would appreciate any help

Comment: Can you clarify how the people answer the questions? If someone gets heads, do they answer the first question with "yes" and the second question with "no"?

Comment: @angryavian If they get heads, they answer the first question with "yes" or "no". If they get tails they answer the second question with "yes" or "no". So getting heads means answering the first question and getting tails the second.

Comment: @angryavian I should add that the participants are given a fair coin. So we do know that p =0.5.

Comment: It seems you don't have any information about how they choose between "yes" or "no" when answering a question; only about which question they choose to respond to?

Comment: @angryavian Yes, we only know which question they chose to answer (depending on the result of the coin-flip)

Comment: Or actually, it seems that if a person chooses to answer the first question, they randomly choose Yes with probability $p_A$. Similarly for the second question, they choose Yes with probability $p_B$. Is this the right interpretation?

Comment: @angryavian I thought so too. The only confusing thing to me now is that it says "the proporition of ppl $p_B$  answering the second question with "yes" is known. $p_A$ is a probability and $p_B < n$ number of ppl answering the second question with yes ? But I did interpret $p_B$ and $p_A$ both to be probabilities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each person has one of four outcomes: $(1, yes)$, $(1, no)$, $(2, yes)$, $(2, no)$, each with respective probabilities $p_A/2$, $(1-p_A)/2$, $p_B/2$, $(1-p_B)/2$.

Your data consists of $n$ such outcomes, and you are asked to estimate $p_A$.

The likelihood of seeing the data is
$$\frac{1}{2^n}p_A^{N_{1,yes}} (1-p_A)^{N_{1, no}} p_B^{N_{2,yes}} (1-p_B)^{N_{2, no}}.$$
Take the logarithm and choose $0<p_A<1$ to maximize it.